# Column Qualifier value max size

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i am thinking about using our HBase as a content management store. I have somewhat large xml documents (5 MB+) which i would like to store.  Is there a limit to the number of bytes i can store in a single column qualifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value is 10 MB. But you can change it through `hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize` property in hbase-site.xml. If you are expecting your data to be very large then you can keep the data in HDFS and store pointers to the data in HBase.